# Input.GetKeyDown not working as intended in a Unity application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to toggle a UI option with the help of a key press, it works with a UI button though but not with an Input.GetKeyDown command.

The code snippet is in a function which is called from the OnGui. "Toggle" toggles a boolean variable which controls if the UI is visible. I then further tried to use the toggle with a separate action (Adding a text to the screen) and it does seem to work but it occurs exactly 6 times with each press (Hence the UI remains off even after the key press.) For more information, the entire UI is in a different class. The snippet is located in a public static function. The function is called from the OnGUI of another active class.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Telelog.Toggle = !Telelog.Toggle;
    }
```

Like when I did the exact same with a button, I expected the UI to pop up when I press the spacebar. Doesn't work as intended tho.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask], [tour], [mcve] as from this we cannot recreate your problem. Please include enough so that is meats the mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`OnGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html)

> might be called several times per frame (one call per event)

so it is called more than once per frame. It is not a good idea to toggle your flag there. `GetKeyDown` is reset at the end of the frame, so it will be `true` for all calls to `OnGUI` in that frame.

---

Better do the toggle in [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html).

Comment: @TejasNayak Also, stop using OnGui. It has been depreciated in favor of the new UI since 4.6 except for Editor panels.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that might have been the issue, but I was too uncertain to act on it. I'd move it to update asap.